# external "booking tool" to allow login through external website

Tags: php, jquery, html, web-services

I have a booking tool which you "install" in an external website by inserting a single javascript from our server in your website and create a div node which we detect, when the javascripts loads, it executes a call to a webservice and then will load the html over a JSON response from our webservices and insert into the div node.

so basically, our tool "melds" with your website and we're very careful to namespace all our css and javascript to stop us from interfering with your website, to the point of a little paranoia :)

once our tool is installed, it runs all the webservices to our server to retrieve data.

the part I'm stuck on, is how to secure the login data, basically, we have a problem here, we don't know the people who own the external website and they are allowing people to register and login to our tool in order to buy our services, we store, process logins and give tickets to events and functions using that tool.

the problem we have is that those credentials can be stolen because the website has access to the html, javascript and probably can do some naughty jquery tricks to grab the username and password data.

I'd like to stop that if possible.

how could I secure the login, so I can embed the tool in any website (http or https) and protect the usernames and passwords entered into the tool and used to login.

any ideas?

Comment: Without more information on exactly what your service is and how it operates, we're just guessing. Can you share a link or a code sample?

Comment: imagine you have a website, you put a div node, with an id='booking_tool'

our javascript when loaded, will update that div with our booking tool, loaded across a webservice (just a PHP webservice, nothing like a java server or anything complex)

the problem is, that html form which takes your username+password, is hosted on your server, your rules, which means if somebody enters the username+password into that, they are actually typing into your website, there are no iframes.

in this scenario, we need to try to find a way to secure that login

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing the problem. If the user does not validate they won't gain entry. It would be that same thing as me simply making a cURL request to your server from my domain.

Comment: That's not possible, Christopher. As you said you have to play by the rules of the person that runs the website and there is absolutely nothing that keeps them from playing 'man in the middle' and logging/faking user data. The only way around this would be to redirect to your site for authentication.

Comment: @Dan I had the idea of opening a https popup to our server, doing the login there and returning an unique string we could both recognise.  then you'd have to run the gauntlet of popup blockers and I'm not even sure it can't be faked in this situation too

Comment: @Dan - Thanks, now I see what Christopher is asking

Comment: @ChristopherThomas what you're describing sounds like a single sign-on mechanism. You can't do it securely by relying solely on client-side technology; that's simply impossible.

Comment: yes I suppose in a way it's like that, it's not totally client side, we control the server side, it's just that the html form used to input the username+password exists in the client side, on the external website.  Of course I trust the client, they are the one owning the device used to login, but the problem is, I don't trust the external website, which could be any bunch of russian hackers for all I know.